# "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure" wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

There's a problem. I have a site, that expanded locally on IIS, that needs to be connected to the remote WCF service. I've added all required certificates to the **TrustedRoot** store of **LocalComputer**. I've granted all permissions to my domain account for using certificates. But there's still a problem:

> "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure"

when I'm trying to run method of WCF-service (but it's connected to this WCF service fine).

I have some thinks about that:

1) Maybe I need to select SSL on IIS setting of this site?

2) Maybe I need to put certificates not only to **LocalMachine**, but to the **CurrentUser** too?

Advice me some tips for how to establish SSL connection and pass this exception. Thank you :)

Comment: You have to make CRL available at both ends - client and server. WCF client needs to validate server certificate against CRL (in whole chain from server certificate to trusted root). The same goes for server WCF host.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the certificate you use on your local IIS, is a virtual one. Probably, you will not get it in real time. There are several hacks available to make it work locally.

NOTE: Never ever do this on production...

Add following code segment(an event handler), before calling any method of service.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        EasyCertCheck;

 bool EasyCertCheck(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
   X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        return true;
    }
```